# How can I make check marks disappear?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a browser that has search engines and I want to make search engine settings where user can choose which search engine he wants to use. I made choosing part and saving engine with shared preferences but when I close the app and open it again, it makes all check marks appear. When I click a search engine, all check marks goes except the one I choosed. How can I make all check marks disappear and appear the one that has been selected before when I open the app. I recorded a video so you can understand what it is.

https://ufile.io/q61jhhel

My code:

```
public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
public static final String SEARCH_ENGINE = "SEARCH_ENGINE";

public String search_engine;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_engine_settings);

    Button back_button = findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    Button google_button = findViewById(R.id.google_button);
    Button yahoo_button = findViewById(R.id.yahoo_button);
    Button yandex_button = findViewById(R.id.yandex_button);
    Button bing_button = findViewById(R.id.bing_button);
    Button duckduckgo_button = findViewById(R.id.duckduckgo_button);
    ImageView google_check = findViewById(R.id.google_check);
    ImageView yahoo_check = findViewById(R.id.yahoo_check);
    ImageView yandex_check = findViewById(R.id.yandex_check);
    ImageView bing_check = findViewById(R.id.bing_check);
    ImageView duckduckgo_check = findViewById(R.id.duckduckgo_check);


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    search_engine = sharedPreferences.getString(SEARCH_ENGINE, "Google");

    Toast.makeText(this, search_engine, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (true) {
        switch (search_engine) {
            case "Google":
                google_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                yahoo_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                yandex_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                bing_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                duckduckgo_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case "Yahoo":
                google_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                yahoo_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                yandex_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                bing_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                duckduckgo_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case "Yandex":
                google_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                yahoo_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                yandex_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bing_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                duckduckgo_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case "Bing":
                google_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                yahoo_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                yandex_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                bing_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                duckduckgo_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case "DuckDuckGo":
                google_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                yahoo_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                yandex_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                bing_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                duckduckgo_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }
    }

    google_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        search_engine = "Google";
        save_engine();
        refresh();
    });

    yahoo_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        search_engine = "Yahoo";
        save_engine();
        refresh();
    });

    yandex_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        search_engine = "Yandex";
        save_engine();
        refresh();
    });

    duckduckgo_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        search_engine = "DuckDuckGo";
        save_engine();
        refresh();
    });

    bing_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        search_engine = "Bing";
        save_engine();
        refresh();
    });

    back_button.setOnClickListener(v -> geriye_donus());
}

public void geriye_donus() {
    Intent geriye_donus = new Intent(this, activity_settings.class);
    startActivity(geriye_donus);
}

public void save_engine() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(SEARCH_ENGINE, search_engine);

    editor.apply();
}

public void refresh() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(this, search_engine, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix the code and remove some unnecessary parts, I'm not sure if this will fix the problem but I hope it will

```
public String search_engine;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_engine_settings);

Button back_button = findViewById(R.id.back_button);
Button google_button = findViewById(R.id.google_button);
Button yahoo_button = findViewById(R.id.yahoo_button);
Button yandex_button = findViewById(R.id.yandex_button);
Button bing_button = findViewById(R.id.bing_button);
Button duckduckgo_button = findViewById(R.id.duckduckgo_button);
ImageView google_check = findViewById(R.id.google_check);
ImageView yahoo_check = findViewById(R.id.yahoo_check);
ImageView yandex_check = findViewById(R.id.yandex_check);
ImageView bing_check = findViewById(R.id.bing_check);
ImageView duckduckgo_check = findViewById(R.id.duckduckgo_check);


SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
search_engine = sharedPreferences.getString("SEARCH_ENGINE", "");
Toast.makeText(this, (search_engine.isEmpty() ? "Google" : search_engine) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
            google_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            yahoo_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            yandex_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bing_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            duckduckgo_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            
    switch (search_engine) {
        case "":
            google_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case "Google":
            google_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case "Yahoo":
            yahoo_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case "Yandex":
            yandex_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case "Bing":
            bing_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case "DuckDuckGo":
            duckduckgo_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }

google_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    search_engine = "Google";
    save_engine();
    refresh();
});

yahoo_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    search_engine = "Yahoo";
    save_engine();
    refresh();
});

yandex_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    search_engine = "Yandex";
    save_engine();
    refresh();
});

duckduckgo_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    search_engine = "DuckDuckGo";
    save_engine();
    refresh();
});

bing_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    search_engine = "Bing";
    save_engine();
    refresh();
});

back_button.setOnClickListener(v -> geriye_donus());
}

public void geriye_donus() {
startActivity(new Intent(this, activity_settings.class));
}

public void save_engine() {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("SEARCH_ENGINE", search_engine).commit();
}

public void refresh() {
startActivity(getIntent());
Toast.makeText(this, (search_engine.isEmpty() ? "Google" : search_engine), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

I also have a better way to make the "search engine selection" functionality ( using the Spinner view ), If you are Interested I can edit your code to use Spinner